'Skipping acquire' error messages when running 'sudo apt update'
I have started to get multiple 'Skipping acquired' error messages when running 'sudo apt update':
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/i18n/Translation-en_ZA' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file '-security/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component '-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

This is the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list:
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

Can anyone please help?

Do you have supplementary .list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d? if so, have you checked them as well? Look for an error like jammy -security in place of jammy-security

Thanks a lot, @steeldriver
I eventually found exactly the error you mentioned in one of the lists in sources.list.d directory

Also thanks to @ArchismanPanigrahi for pointing me to that post
